# Calcular números perfectos de acuerdo a la cantidad que quiera ver el usuario

Tags: c#, numero-perfecto

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito lograr hacer que el programa me muestre los números perfectos de acuerdo a la cantidad de números perfectos que quiera ver el usuario, es decir, que el programa me pregunte cuantos números perfectos quiero ver, al ingresar 6 por ej, que este me muestre los primeros 6 números perfectos, o que al ingresar 8, este me muestre los primero 8 números perfectos, les dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora gracias, muchas gracias!!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num; 
        int cont1 = 0;

        Console.Write("Ingrese numero a evaluar: "); 
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                cont1 = i + cont1;
            }
        }

        cont1 = cont1 - num;

        if (cont1 == num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Es perfecto");
        }

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Le agregue mas que nada las etiquetas de los otros lenguajes para ver si mas gente se motivaba a ayudar, ya que esto es solo lógica que se puede ejecutar por consola, nada de formularios o web, y a que te refieres con que no comento nada respecto a la pregunta??

Comment: primero debe de separar los conceptos del problema, el programa que coloco calcula si un número es perfecto, esa es una parte del problema, ahora lo que debe hacer es englobar todo el proceso en un `do-while` que este condicionado por una variable auxiliar que lleve el conteo de los número encontrados, y que cada vez que encuentre uno lo imprima por pantalla y aumente en uno el conteo auxiliar.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar mostrándome código?? Ya lo estoy haciendo con un ciclo while, pero este problema me ha dado un verdadero dolor de cabeza, por favor !!

Comment: Aparte del ciclo, hay otro problema que es el algoritmo... una división por tentativa para obtener los divisores está muy bien para los 4 primeros números perfectos, el quinto es ya 33550336, el sexto 8589869056 y  el séptimo  137438691328, el octavo 2305843008139952128... Pronto se va de las manos...

Answer (score 1):

Que tal amigo supongo que estas aprendiendo a programar de forma que use una solución básica y que sea fácil de comprender pero aun así tienes que afinar el proceso ya que hay muchas cosas imprecisas.

Usé un ciclo while donde este se repitiera hasta que n(La cantidad de numeros perfectos que el usuario requiere) deje de ser mayor al contador ,el contador suma cada que comprueba que un numero es perfecto si se ingresa un numero que no lo es no se contara y el programa se detendrá hasta que ingreses n números que al comprobarlos sean perfectos

Aquí el código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cuantos numeros perfectos quiere ver ?");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int contador = 0;

    while (n > contador)
    {
        int num;
        int cont1 = 0;
        Console.Write("Ingrese numero a evaluar: ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                cont1 = i + cont1;
            }
        }

        cont1 = cont1 - num;

        if (cont1 == num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Es perfecto");
            ++contador;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No voy a colocar todo el código, solo dare algunas pautas con una posible solución:

**1. Crear un método que evalue si un número es perfecto**

```
static boolean isPerfect(int numero){
  int sumaDivisores = 0;
  int limiteEvaluar = numero/2; //no es necesario evaluar la otra mitad
  for(int i = 1; i <= limiteEvaluar; i++){
    //aca código que evalua si i es divisor y lo suma a sumaDivisores
  }
  return (sumaDivisores == numero);
}
```

**2. En el método Main**

```
int cantidadSolicitada = //valor que ingrese el usuario
int contadorNumerosPerfectosEncontrados = 0;
int numero = 1;

while(contadorNumerosPerfectosEncontrados < cantidadSolicitada){
  if(isPerfect(numero)){
    //imprime el número y aumente contador de numeros perfectos encontrados en uno
  }
  //aumente número en uno
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para darle solución a esta problemática declaramos la **clase Matematica** la cual tendrá dos métodos:

**Divisores**: Recibe un entero como parámetro y devuelve una lista de enteros con todos los divisores del número pasado por parámetro. Los divisores de un número pueden obtenerse dividiendo el número por todos los números que se encuentran entre **1** y la raíz cuadrada del propio número, por ejemplo para hallar los divisores de **100**, tendríamos que dividir **100** entre todos los números que se hallan entre **1** y **10** (raíz cuadrada de **100**). De esta forma obtendríamos como divisores de **100** los números **2**, **4**, **5**, **10**, **20**, **25**, **50**(El **20**, **25** y **50** no se encuentran entre el **1** y la raíz cuadrada de **100** pero llegamos a ellos dividiendo entre **5**, **4** y **2**, que si se encuentran en el rango de **1** y la raíz cuadrada de **100**). Eso es precisamente lo que hace esta función, primero se declara la **lista de enteros divisores** y la **variable raiz** que almacenará la raíz cuadrada del número que se pasa por parámetro, posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for** que irá desde **1** hasta la **variable raiz**. Dentro de este **ciclo for** se pregunta si el número es divisible por **i**, de serlo se guarda a la **variable i** en la lista de divisores, se hace la división y el resultado de esta división también se guarda en la lista de divisores, ejemplo: **100** es divisible por **2**, se guarda el **2** en la lista de divisores, se divide **100 / 2** y ese resultado que sería **50** se guarda también en la lista de divisores. Finalmente se retornaría la lista de divisores obtenidos.

**EsPerfecto**: Esta función es la responsable de determinar si un número es o no es un **número perfecto**. **Un número perfecto es un número entero positivo que es igual a la suma de sus divisores propios positivos**. Ejemplo, el número **28**, sus divisores son: **1**, **2**, **4**, **7**, **14** y la suma de estos divisores **1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28** por tanto es un **número perfecto**. Esta función recibe un entero y devuelve un **bool**. Dentro de esta función se invoca a la **función Divisores** explicada anteriormente, se suman los divisores obtenidos y si esa suma es igual al número pasado por parámetro se retorna **true** indicando que el número es perfecto, caso contrario se retorna **false** indicando que el número no es perfecto.

```
public static class Matematica
{
    public static List<int> Divisores(int n)
    {
        List<int> divisores = new List<int>();
        int raiz = (int)Math.Sqrt(n);

        for (int i = 1; i <= raiz; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                divisores.Add(i);

                if (n / i != i)
                {
                    divisores.Add(n / i);
                }
            }
        }

        return divisores;
    }

    public static bool EsNumeroPerfecto(int n)
    {
        var sumaDivisores = Divisores(n).Sum() - n;
        return sumaDivisores == n;
    }
}
```

Para hacer uso de esta clase según tus necesidades haríamos lo siguiente:

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el total de números perfectos que desea obtener:");

int totalNumerosPerfectos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int contadorNumerosPerfectos = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Lista de números perfectos:");

for (int i = 1; i <= int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    if (contadorNumerosPerfectos == totalNumerosPerfectos)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (Matematica.EsNumeroPerfecto(i))
    {
        contadorNumerosPerfectos++;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} es un número perfecto", i);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Aquí se declara a la **variable totalNumerosPerfectos** que servirá para almacenar la cantidad de **números perfectos** que queremos obtener, y se declara además la **variable contadorNumerosPerfectos** que servirá para ir contando cada vez que encontramos un **número perfecto**. Posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for** que recorrerá todos los números enteros y se detendrá cuando la **variable contadorNumerosPerfectos** sea igual a la **variable totalNumerosPerfectos** o bien se llegue al final del **ciclo for**. Dentro de este **ciclo for** invocamos a la **función EsPerfecto** explicada anteriormente, de devolver **true** se imprime que el número es perfecto, caso contrario se imprime que el número no es perfecto.

**Referencias**:

https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_perfecto

https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisi%C3%B3n_por_tentativa

https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorizaci%C3%B3n_de_enteros

Comment: Ya quisiera saber por que le han dado votos negativos a la respuesta. Tiene algo mal?

Comment: @Excorpion por maldad e ignorancia